# Which wire is the C wire?

Tags: thermostat, wire

Model: Goodman AWB30-08C Electric AC/Heat

I'm hoping someone can help me identify the 24V C wire. Fortunately the thermostat line has a spare wire already run, so I just need to find the C wire in the HVAC. See diagrams below:

[image]

[image]

I can also post a pic of the exposed wiring if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wire labeled `BL` in both images, should be the `C` wire. `W` and `BR` activate the heat relay. `G` activates the blower time delay relay. `PK` takes 24v to the thermostat.

If you're looking for the `C` wire, because you want to install a fancy new WiFi thermostat.  Make sure the transformer can support the additional load, before you connect the thermostat. It doesn't look like there's a fuse on the transformer, and you wouldn't want to burn up the transformer.